# I can't update my ubuntu (17.04)

Tags: upgrade, 17.04, do-release-upgrade

my ubuntu is 17.04 and now I can't upgrade because of this error

[image: Error]

Comment: 17.04 is EoL. Please upgrade to a supported release.

Comment: how can I upgrade?!

Comment: @FlorianDiesch Thank you! , this solved the problem.